# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I get this error(ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError) when I use async pipe! The code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so58276430-attempt-solution-1lnzpr).
Where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is coming from `{{users$|async|json}}`.
In layout service, it returns null and trying to display it causes an error.

I tested like that and I do not have any error.

```html
  <h1>Layout Component</h1>
  <div>
    <div *ngIf="layoutService.getSpinnerState|async">
      <span>SPINING...
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>StateSpinner: {{ layoutService.getSpinnerState|async }} </p>
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.layoutService.withSpinner(this.profileService.getUser()).subscribe();
  }
```

edit :

If I understand, the error, it is the change in your observable that makes it.

you can do something like that, when you call your layout service. What do you think ? It looks cleaner to me.

```
withSpinner<T>(obs:Observable<T>){
    this.setSpinnerState(true)
    return obs.pipe(
      delay(2000),
      finalize(()=>this.setSpinnerState(false))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Look at the error again: "ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: [object Object]'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'."

Comment: It's not a good reactive programming practice. Because the spinner is activated even though no one has subscribed to it yet.

Comment: That's not the problem anyway.

Comment: I see your point. If you want want to do it the right way in case you want a loader in every http request, you could simply use an interceptor for your http request.
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor